# Change delay of setInverval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tweeter feed. The feed shows a small `div` with some animation, first it checks if the `div` `display` property its `:none` if so, it toggles the visibility and writes some info from a a json file. But, If its `display: block` it hides the 'div'.

Now I want to change the 'delay' value for 'setInterval' using the 'if' 'else' inside the function. But I can't get to change it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var delay = 2000;
    setInterval(function() {
        var isVisible = $('#container').css("display") == "none";
        if(isVisible) {
            delay = 10000;

            $("#container").toggle( "clip", "slow" );
            $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
                document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h1>@" 
                + data.user.screen_name + "</h1>";
            });
        }
        else {
            delay = 1000;
            $("#container").toggle( "clip", "slow" );
        }
    }, delay );
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to clear current interval and start a new one with the new delay value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case you can try use setTimeout:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var delay = 2000,
        toggleDiv;

    toggleDiv = function() {
        var isVisible = $('#container').css("display") == "none";
        if(isVisible) {
            setTimeout(toggleDiv, 10000);

            $("#container").toggle( "clip", "slow" );
            $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
                document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h1>@" 
                + data.user.screen_name + "</h1>";
            });
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(toggleDiv, 1000);
            $("#container").toggle( "clip", "slow" );
        }
    };

    setTimeout(toggleDiv, delay);
});
```

Comment: Wow... I need to read this carefully and understand how it works because it works perfectly. It does what I want. Really, really thanks.

Comment: Nice, begin reading [this post](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) then read about each method at [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers).

Answer (score 0):

To change the interval you need to clear the existing one and create a new one.

```
var interval = setInterval(callback, delay);
clearInterval(interval);
interval = setInterval(callback, newDelay);
```

It is always a good idea to assign your intervals and timeouts to a `var`. Then you have the handle to clear then via `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval.`

Comment: This one is really useful also! I'll take in consideration this.